# WebLogic Cluster balancer always route to second node

Tags: weblogic, cluster-computing, soa

I have configured Apache to load balance two WebLogic nodes (using mod_weblogic),
but all requests are forwarded to second node.

Here what I have added to httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule weblogic_module modules/mod_wl_22.so
<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
MatchExpression /soa-infra WebLogicCluster=node1.domain.com:8001,node2.domain.com:8001
</IfModule>
<Location /soa-infra>
SetHandler weblogic-handler
WebLogicCluster node1.domain.com:8001,node2.domain.com:8001
</Location>
```

What I have tried with no effect:

```
1) swap node1.domain.com and node2.domain.com
2) change balancing algorithm in WebLogic Administration Console
```

Some clarifications:
    1. client is adressing apache - I am testing myself.
    2. I see that apache is creating connection only after request from client/me and it is only connection to second node (on which it is executing).
    3. yes, both nodes are in local network and are reachable.
I have found interesting thing:
if I remove all my lines from httpd.conf except line for loading mod_weblogic and restart apache then I have no access via load-balancer - so balancer is really using my config lines,
but if I remove second node from list then load balancer are still redirecting second node instead of only one listed first node.

Looks like I have found issue!

After several requests I see in log:

```
Wed Jan 25 19:56:49 2012 <480013275070093> Trying a pooled connection for '192.168.0.111/8001/8001'
Wed Jan 25 19:56:49 2012 <480013275070093> getPooledConn: No more connections in the pool for Host[192.168.0.111] Port[8001] SecurePort[8001]
Wed Jan 25 19:56:49 2012 <480013275070093> general list: trying connect to '192.168.0.111'/8001/8001 at line 2724 for '/soa-infra/services/partition/my_composite/my_composite_client_ep'

Wed Jan 25 19:57:05 2012 <480013275070256> Trying to locate Primary or Secondary using SrvrInfo with JVMID: -76285319
Wed Jan 25 19:57:05 2012 <480013275070256> getPreferredFromCookie: Found Primary 192.168.0.112:8001:0
Wed Jan 25 19:57:05 2012 <480013275070256> getPreferredFromCookie: Found 1 servers
```

192.168.0.111 is a first node, 192.168.0.112 - second.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Cluster is multicast (not unicast).

Comment: I have not done this:
    http://www.javaoracleblog.com/java/Installing_an_11g_SOA_Cluster_8211_Part_IV_More_Configuration.jsf
Setting SOA/BPM Frontend Host & Cluster Address.
Can this be a reason?

Comment: Unfortunately removing cookies from my browser haven't helped.
Also I have noticed that my test request to get wsdl of composite from soa_server is not creating any cookies in browser and now load balancer is not telling getPreferredFromCookie any more. Just still forwarding to second node.
But also now I have noticed next line in log:
Fri Jan 27 16:23:20 2012 <455613276670002> Hdrs from WLS:[X-WebLogic-Cluster-List]=[-76285319!node2.domain.com!8001!-1]

Answer (score 0):

`Hdrs from WLS:[X-WebLogic-Cluster-List]=[-76285319!node2.domain.com!8001!-1]`

WebLogic server in node2 is not aware of the rest of the cluster. Please ensure you cluster is working ok.

If using Unicast messaging, you can check groups are created ok.

[image: ServerGroup]